# Select option doesn't post correctly after being manipulated with javascript

Tags: jquery, select, post

I have a select field where the content changes depending on another select field. With the my script disabled, my selection posts fine and is inserted in my DB. However, when I mess with the select field with javascript, my posted value defaults to the default one ("1"). I am also running chzn (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but the problem persists even with it disabled. Here is my JS :

```
$(function() {
    var $dropdown = $("#type");
    var $for = $("#for");

    $for.clone().attr('id', 'for2' ).insertAfter($for).hide();
    $for2 = $('#for2');

    function getType() {
        $type = $dropdown.val();
        return $type;
    }

    function checkType($type) {
        if ($type == 1) {
            $for.find('.skin').remove();
            $for2.find('.champion').clone().appendTo($for).trigger("liszt:updated");
        } else if ($type == 2) {
            $for.find('.champion').remove();
            $for2.find('.skin').clone().appendTo($for).trigger("liszt:updated");
        }
    }

    getType();
    checkType($type);

    $dropdown.change(function() {
        getType();
        checkType($type);
    });
});
```

What causes this issue? Thanks for looking :)

***edit*** Running `alert($for.find($("option:selected")).text());` indeed returns my selected option. I really don't understand why it is not getting posted.

***edit2*** I can get it to work by appending a (hidden) text field, and setting it's value when my select changes, and of course updating my controller to use the "for-value" :

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'for-value', name: 'for-value' }).insertAfter($for).hide();
$forValue = $('#for-value');

$for.change(function() {
    $forVal = $for.val();
    $forValue.val($forVal);
});
```

But this is so ugly.... why can't I get it to work the regular way? Am I missing something?

***edit3***
As requested, HTML :

```
<form action="insert" method="POST">

    ...

    <label for="type">type</label>
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="1">Champion</option>
        <option value="2">Skin</option>
    </select>

    <label for="for">For</label>
    <select id="for" name="for">
        @foreach ($skins as $skin)
        <option class="skin" value="{{ $skin->id }}">{{ $skin->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @foreach ($champions as $champion)
        <option class="champion" value="{{ $champion->id }}">{{ $champion->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    ...

    <button>Insert</button>

</form>
```

***edit4*** Even worse, as suggested by Stano to include a name while cloning makes it work, it even works if I remove the attribute during the chain :

```
$for.clone().attr('id', 'for2').insertAfter($for).hide(); //doesn't work.
$for.clone().attr({ id: 'for2', name: 'for2' }).insertAfter($for).hide(); //works
$for.clone().attr({ id: 'for2', name: 'for2' }).removeAttr('name')
    .insertAfter($for).hide(); //works even if I remove the attribute
```

Comment: Just one thing to mention - you're returning $type from the getType function but not storing it, i.e. $type = getType(); however you haven't declared $type with var in the function so it would be global anyway.

Comment: do I really need to store it? I'm executing the function on load. I'm not sure if I'm following what you're trying to say.

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP. The values are posted fine without the JS. Name is set. If I use a text field and set it's value to my select value on change, I can get it to work, however, like this : `array ( ... 'type' => '2', 'for' => '1', 'for-value' => '6', ... )` for-value is the value of my text field using `$('#for-value').val($for.val());`

Comment: can we have HTML codes?

Comment: yes, I've updated my question with the HTML.

Comment: `console.log($forVal)` outputs the right value. Yes I am already setting the text field using `$forValue.val($forVal)` and it works fine. It posts the correct value. Why can't I get the select to post the correct value? I'm so puzzled.

Comment: Yes the value is updated correcty, as far as I know, running an alert or console log on change with the value of the select returns the correct value. Anyways... I will use this ugly solution for now until I figure this out. Thanks you for trying :)

Comment: POST result : `array ( ... 'type' => '2', 'for' => '4', 'for-value' => '4', 'for2' => '1', ... )` Taking down the name of "for2" results in "for" being 1.

Comment: As a follow up, your method of including the attribute works even if I remove the name right after, like this : `$for.clone().attr({ id: 'for2', name: 'for2' }).removeAttr('name')
    .insertAfter($for).hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Cloning the object would also take the `name` with it, and posting would take the last `name` referenced in the HTML, which was the copy of the first `select`. This is why it would always return 1.

Removing, or renaming the `name` attribute during the chain counters this, like so :

```
$for.clone().attr('id', 'for2').removeAttr('name').insertAfter($for).hide();
```